# How to close element when click outside the element using AngularJs Only?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my code

```js
$scope.searchHide = function() {
  $scope.selectMenuSetting = "SearchPanel";
  $scope.secondPanelShow = !$scope.secondPanelShow;
  $scope.secondColumn = false;
};

$scope.showSearchPopUp = function() {
  $scope.selectMenuSetting = "SearchPopUp";
  $scope.secondColumn = !$scope.secondColumn;
  $scope.secondPanelShow = false;
};
```

```html
<div class="tab-panel">
  <a href="" class="second-panel-search" click-anywhere-but-here ng-click="searchHide()"><i class="nc-icon-mini ui-1_zoom" ng-class="{'active': selectMenuSetting === 'SearchPanel'}"></i></a>
  <a href="" class="second-panel-search" click-anywhere-but-here ng-click="showSearchPopUp()"><i class="nc-icon-mini ui-3_select" ng-class="{'active': selectMenuSetting === 'SearchPopUp'}"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="second-search-hide-panel padt5" ng-if="secondPanelShow">
  <div class="second-search-input ">
    <input type="text" placeholder="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="refreshData(searchText)"><i class="nc-icon-mini ui-1_zoom active"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-search-hide-panel" ng-if="secondColumn">
   <div class="second-search-input" ng-if="showObjectTypes">
  <div class="second-search-input">
            <label class="control-label">Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="objectType" ng-change="callingGetData(objectType)">
              <option value="major">Major Objects</option>
              <option value="support">Supporting Objects</option>
              <option value="lookup">LookUp Objects</option>
           </select>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In the above code contains two anchor tags. When I click first anchor tag display search text field and when click second anchor tag show dropdown. But, when I click outside the element I want to hide the anchor tags using AngularJS without using jQuery.

Comment: I had an issue like this when using popover.
My solution was to add an attribute (exclude) in the body then in my element I'm checking if the on the click element we have the exclude attribute

Comment: So you want to perform something when you lose focus right ? it's the directive ng-blur for this.

Answer (score 0):

This needs the ng-blur directive on the element, although i'm not sure why you want to use nothing but Angular...